# If I copy an Excel document with procedures scheduled via Application.OnTime, is the schedule copied to the new document?

Tags: excel, vba

It's a very simple question, but I can't find an answer to it anywhere.

Maybe some more information is necessary. I have a workbook with some procedures schedules in the future.

Now I know there is no easy way to get rid of the schedules, so I wonder if I were to copy the document, would the schedule be copied too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Application.OnTime` you'll schedule procedures within the scope of the current Application object. E.g. if you close it, all active schedules will be cancelled.

It might be that the scheduled runs are set in a `Workbook_Open` event or something similar - In that case the schedule will be reinstated as soon as you open the (copied or original) document.

As implied by Zeretil his answer: the schedule will refer to the workbook's procedure when the schedule was created. When you copy and open the workbook, this will not change and the procedure in the copy will of course not run.
If you close the application with the original workbook, the schedule will also stop running.

Last but not least: There is an easy way to cancel the schedule in the current workbook, by using the `Schedule` parameter of the `OnTime` method:
To cancel the schedule for procedure "test":

**Edit: Included schedule at variable time + cancel at the set time**

```
Sub RunTestOnTime()
Dim eTime as Variant
eTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:20") 'Store the time in a variable

Application.Ontime EarliestTime:=eTime, Procedure:="test" 'Schedule it
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=eTime, Procedure:="test", Schedule:=False 'Delete schedule.
End Sub
```

Complete documentation on the `OnTime` method [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel)

Comment: @YowE3K Yes you're absolutely right. Amended the code snippet accordingly.

Comment: @YowE3K Although that would be good practice, it's out of scope for a minimal example of "How do I cancel a schedule" and thus doesn't have to be included in the answer.

Comment: BTW - I am going to do a test tomorrow (if I remember) - I know that Excel will force the workbook to be re-opened if the user has closed it and it is now time to run the macro, but I'm not sure whether Excel will suppress running the `Workbook_Open` event in that case.  If it **does** run it, we could end up with multiple scheduled events if the `Open` also  schedules an event.  (Things always get interesting when you stop using linear code flow!)

Comment: The schedule is in the application scope. If you close the app it won't run. If you close only the workbook it will reopen it to run the procedure.

Comment: I was going to ask this but can only confirm that what @RikSportel says is correct. It will reopen the workbook when Excel is still running, but when the Excel process is stopped the workbook will not open. I did not know this also means the ontime events are canceled. This helps me greatly during testing!

Comment: I did my test and the answer is that, yes, the `Workbook_Open` **is** executed when the workbook is reopened to execute the macro.  That means that, if the `Workbook_Open` code is set up to start the schedule and then the workbook is closed/auto-reopened, you will have two instances of the event running (and three if you close the workbook again, etc), so including the initiation of the scheduled task in `Workbook_Open` is potentially dangerous if there is any chance that the workbook will be closed before the scheduled task is cancelled.  (This assumes the invoked macro reschedules itself.)

Answer (score 0):

So because I am a very impatient man I decided to test it myself.

Here is the code I used:

[image: Testcode]

While the "test" procedure was being executed correctly every 20 seconds, I copied and opened the copy of the workbook.
[image: Workbooks]

The schedule did in fact not get copied, so copying and replacing your document seems like the easiest solution to getting rid of OnTime events. Renaming your document to the original name does not cause the schedule to run on the copied document.